# Querying MongoDB via C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am looking to write a simple c# web api application, the APi will return the JSON from mongodb for any given search parameter. I am trying to see if I can achieve this without using any POCO objects, the aim is to connect to Mongodb, Query with given parameters and return whatever JSON object to the client, I need not know the schema of JSON.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to use BsonDocument instead of a class. BsonDocument is the .NET MongoDB Driver's type that can represent any type of document. So, take in JSON, parse it into a BsonDocument (BsonDocument.Parse(json)). On the way out, use the ToString() method on BsonDocument.